# Fake roots of a Complex Equation.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

I am looking for the roots of the complex function $f(x)=1+(ix)^N, N\in R$,

$\Rightarrow 1+(ix)^N= 0$

$\Rightarrow (ix)^N=-1$

$\Rightarrow ix=(-1)^{1/N}$

$\Rightarrow ix=(e^{i(2k+1)\pi})^{1/N} , k=0,1,2,3.....$

Roots are given as, $ ~x=-i e^{i(2k+1)\pi /N  }, k=0,1,2,3.....$.

Now first four roots $(k=0,1,2,3)$ for $N=3.6$ are given as: 
{$0.766044 - 0.642788 i,0.5 + 0.866025 i, -0.939693 + 0.34202 i,$ and  $ -0.173648 - 0.984808i$}.

Now, if I put back them into $f(x)$, then -

$$\{0,~0,~ 1.80902 - 0.587785 i,~ 1.80902 - 0.587785 i \}$$

So only two are genuine roots, rest two are fake.

Now the Ques is: what/where I am missing for getting the fake roots?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Could you tell us what is $I^+$ ?

Comment: @tmaths, Sorry, It should have been R, not $I^+$, Edited!

Comment: Your formula is only valid for $N\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: If $N\not\in\mathbb N$, your equation is not polynomial and de Moivre's formula doesn't apply. Do you know definition of $x^N$ for $N\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: @tmaths,Can't we define like that -  $i^\pi= (e^{i(2k+1)\pi/2})^\pi, k=0,1,2,3..$

Comment: @gammatester, Could you please more clear that How my formula is not valid for $N \in \cal{N}$

Comment: Sachin, if you don't know about [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) and [branch cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts), your question doesn't have satisfying answer.

Comment: Please detail how exactly you obtained the four values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, You mean: more precise values, if yes, then I have edited the ques.

Comment: @Sachin: no, I don't care about the digits, but about the formulas.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Oh! I m sorry, last four values I obtained by putting the first four roots in $f(x)=1+(ix)^{3.6}$.

Comment: @Sachin: and how did you compute these powers ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust,   using Mathematica

Comment: The solutions are right (up to numerics). The evaluation of $f(x) = 1 + \exp( N\cdot \ln(ix) )$ in the test is wrong.

Comment: @Tobias, How ?? could you please elaborate, where/what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Sachin Just do the checking by hand and really use $f(x) = 1 + \exp( N\cdot \ln(ix) )$. (Each step is simple. Just substitute $x$ with your solution and you will see.) I don't know (and don't care) what Mathematica really does with your input.

Comment: Sachin, what's wrong is that when you evaluate at different $k$'s, you are crossing a branch cut when switching from $k=1$ to $k=2$ (note that $(2k+1)\pi/N $ is less than $\pi$ for $k = 1$ and greater than $\pi$ for $k = 2$), and Mathematica presumably uses only principal branch of logarithm for evaluation, so the result messes up because of discontinuity. Vaguely speaking, the issue is that $N$ is not integer - if it were, "messed up" results would "magically align", hence de Moivre formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for help @Tobias

Comment: Thank you very much for help @Ennar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you have used cannot be correct because

- you compute some complex number of the form $x^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ can exceed $2\pi$;
- you express it in Cartesian form, hence argument information is lost.
- you take the exponential.

So you are not computing

$$e^{i N\theta}$$ but $$e^{iN(\theta\bmod 2\pi)}.$$